# Framework Bundle Format is ambiguous

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks, codesign

I am creating Mac OSx App on 10.9.5 with Xcode 6. I have used Developer ID Application for Generate ".app". I am not able to run this ".app" on other Mac with same Configuration.
The Error which I am facing is

> WSBluetoothFramework.framework/: bundle format is ambiguous (could be
>   app or framework)

**Structure of Framework before Creating ".app"**
[image]

**Structure of Framework after Creating ".app"**
[image]

I have spend 8 hours still not find any solution, Can anyone have idea about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download ".app" file through mail it changed its structure. So To solved that I have created Installer from ".app" and then send through Mail.

Answer (score 1):

It changes structure is only a vague hint.
Most likely, symlinks got broken. (i.e. replaced with copies)

In a different case, using Sparkle-1.18.1 I had to make sure that all symlinks inside the sparkle framwork source remain intact. If not, codesign gives this all-misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. Cause of symlinks.
You can read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html.

By adding symlinks(delete files and using ln -s), I change the structure of the xxx.framework as follows.
**Attention**: Use relative paths to create symlinks!

```
---------------------------------------------------
xxx.framework
    xxx  ->  Versions/Current/xxx
    Resources  ->  Versions/Current/Resources
    Headers  ->  Versions/Current/Headers
    Versions
----------------------------------------------------
xxx.framework/Versions
    A
    Current  ->  A
```